# Is it possible to use environment variables in php.ini?

Tags: php, configuration, environment-variables

Rather than hard-wiring some paths in my php.ini configuration, I'd like to configure them using system variables that are shared in some other places such as my Apache configuration.  I've done some searching and couldn't find the right mix of keywords to discover if there's a way to do this.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

```
upload_tmp_dir = $SCRATCH_HOME/uploads
```

Now SCRATCH_HOME can be exported in the environment as /tmp or /var/scratch or whatever I want it to be.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Documented officially: https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php#example-36

Before I begin, I just want to specify my configurations:
I'm using Windows 7-64bit, PHP 5.4.3, Apache HTTP Server 2.2.x, I've set my environmental variable `PHP_HOME=C:\tools\php-5.4.3` (PHP installation directory).
I use the variable in my `httpd.conf` and `php.ini` file

Note: I will be omitting some text for brevity.

In the `httpd.conf` file

```
# For PHP 5 do something like this:
LoadModule php5_module "${PHP_HOME}/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "${PHP_HOME}"
```

In the `php.ini` file

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "${PHP_HOME}/ext"
```

Comment: Correct. Beware - use slash (/) in your envvar and always doublequote-in-use if there was spaces!

Answer (score 19):

According to the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php), environment-variables can indeed be used in the configuration file.

[image: Screenshot of php docs with URL and note about envvars being allowed in PHP.ini]

It doesn’t say anything about what syntax to use, but it is the same as with Apache’s configuration file which uses *nix syntax. So for example, if you want PHP to use the system temp-directory, you would use this:

```
upload_tmp_dir = ${Temp}
```

You can confirm that it is active with the following script:

```
<?php
    echo "ini:  " . ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') . "\n";
    echo "env:  " . sys_get_temp_dir()        . "\n";
    echo "temp: " . getenv('temp')            . "\n";
    echo "tmp:  " . getenv('tmp')             . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Is it possible to set some default value if the env. var is not set like `${Temp:<default value>}` - is the available grammar of `${...}` somewhere defined/documented?

Comment: @mvorisek I had the same question, and no, it's not currently possible. So I went ahead and implemented it: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/11351

Answer (score 4):

You can use it, and it is well documented now:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php#example-36

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring PHP via [Apache config files](https://www.php.net/configuration.changes#configuration.changes.apache):

```
PHP_admin_value upload_tmp_dir $SCRATCH_HOME/uploads
```

Works fine for me. (psst, you cannot change `upload_tmp_dir` using .htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @Synetec answer, use [get_cfg_var()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-cfg-var.php) if your variable is a custom php.ini variable (created by you, not an official PHP ini directive). For example:

In php.ini: `custom_variable = "abcde"`
In any php script: `get_cfg_var('custom_variable')` returns `abcde`

I use this in in a small project in local dev. As I run the local server via `php -S localhost:8000 -c php.ini` (not running an Apache server locally), it's a good option to call some configuration constants. In production, these constants are set in `.htaccess`.