# Dynamic path in php.ini - possible?

Tags: php, linux, cpanel, shared-hosting

I want to set a "dynamic" value for error log in php.ini - something like this:

```
error_log = /home/{USER}/error_log
```

So that all users always have a single PHP error log file in the same location (their home dir).

My environment is CloudLinux and cPanel, and I can set this manually for every user in their cPanel account, but I'd rather have this on a global level.

Is this possible at all?

**EDIT**: the {USER} part should be dynamic, so unlike [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858431/is-it-possible-to-use-environment-variables-in-php-ini) I can't export it as environment variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10570766/5351549

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use environment variables in php.ini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858431/is-it-possible-to-use-environment-variables-in-php-ini)

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge about this, but PHP_HOME looks like some internal PHP variable, isn't it? And it'll probably be static since PHP dir won't change. In my case USER refers to Linux username, so it must be dynamic. Or maybe I'm not getting something here?