# Can I add non standard php.ini settings to use in my application

Tags: php, apache, configuration, ini

I'm trying to move "environment-dependent" settings to php.ini so things like debugging or what DB credentials to use are all stored in php.ini on each server.

I would normally use .env files in the root (the Laravel way) but this is for work and the desired way is in php.ini. However, I can't see any of new settings I add.

The settings are:

```
[app]
app.debug.on=false
app.debug.level=2
```

I've tried putting the above directly in php.ini and in .user.ini in the root of my application but neither worked.

Restarted Apache and killed all PHP processes also but no matter what I do I never see the new settings when I `var_dump` `ini_get_all()`

Is this even possible or are the setting in php.ini the only valid ones recognized?

Thanks

**Edit (2018-06-29):**

ENV variables won't work because we have dozens of settings. Numerous Datasources which differ from dev to testing to production.

Using php.ini is desired because it gets loaded into memory before the application so no overhead.

Comment: Wouldn't using constants in a "master" file be more accurate ? Or maybe you can't identify everything from PHP itself about the environment ?

Comment: Possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858431/is-it-possible-to-use-environment-variables-in-php-ini

Comment: Personally, I want to do them as ENV variables but that's been rejected. So php.ini was a suggestion because it gets loaded into memory BEFORE the application so it shouldn't impact memory usage.So loading a file from the application is a last resort right now...but I might end up suggesting it if php.ini won't work

Comment: @mlewis54 Unfortunately ENV vars aren't a viable option because we have a lot of settings which we want to abstract out of the codebase.

Comment: @LukeWatts Understood. However, I believe there was a way described in that link to specify how to do what you want in php.ini. It may be the second or third answer down.

Comment: @mlewis54 They're explaining ENV vars can be used as values in php.ini. But all the examples are simply setting which are standard in php.ini. I'm looking to see if I can add new settings that are not standard to php.ini. I don't actually think it's possible...so I'm just going to load a custom ini file at runtime instead I think

Comment: @LukeWatts relying on my admittedly poor memory, I believe it had something to do with a {item} type of syntax. When I get a chance to delve into again I'll take a look in more depth. I'm traveling all this week.

Comment: @mlewis54 Thanks you, but honestly, don't spend any unnecessary time on this. I'm fine with loading a specific php.ini file in using `parse_ini_file()`. The team agreed on that in our last dev review so it's solved. I am curious if it's possible but after trying and reading everything I could on it I never once saw an example that wasn't using the already existing "keys". But thank you for the links and the time you've spent!